# PrivateRoute - how to wait a response from async?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a PrivateRoute that verify if a token is valid and it's an async function. The problem is: my validation to render a view is not working, it's always rendering:

App.js

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      isAuthenticated() ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/", state: { from: props.location } }} />
      )
    }
  />
);

const Routes = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Fragment>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={SignIn} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/app" component={App} />
      </Switch>
      <ModalContainer />
    </Fragment>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default Routes;
```

auth.js

```
import axios from 'axios'

export const isAuthenticated = async () => {
  const isValidRequest = false;

  const resp = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8080...')
  data = resp.data;
  console.log(data);

  ....// more code

  return isValidRequest;  
}
```

How can I ensure that PrivateRoute will wait for function `isAuthenticated()`?

update 1:

```
const Routes = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({isLoading: true, authenticated: false});
  useEffect(() => {
    async function checkAuth() {
        const isAuth = await isAuthenticated();
        setState({isLoading: false, authenticated: isAuth});
    }
  }, []);

  if(state.isLoading) {
     return <div>Loading....</div>
  }
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Fragment>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={SignIn} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/app" isAuthenticated={state.authenticated} component={App} />
        </Switch>
        <ModalContainer />
      </Fragment>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `isAuthenticated` in all `PrivateRoutes`, you call it once in your `Routes component` so that the check is only performed once and then pass on the value as prop. Also note that while the data is being fetched maintain a loading state

Note, that your `isAuthenticated` function is an async function so you have to wait till the promise is resolved. You can use `async-await` or go by the traditional promise approach

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, isAuthenticated, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      isAuthenticated ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/", state: { from: props.location } }} />
      )
    }
  />
);

const Routes = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({isLoading: true, authenticated: false});
    useEffect(() => {
      async function checkAuth() {
         const isAuth = await isAuthenticated();
         setState({isLoading: false, authenticated: isAuth});
     }
      checkAuth();
   }, []);
    if(state.isLoading) {
       return <Loader/>
    }
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Fragment>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={SignIn} />
            <PrivateRoute path="/app" isAuthenticated={state.authenticated} component={App} />
          </Switch>
          <ModalContainer />
        </Fragment>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );

}

export default Routes;
```

---

Update: Since you do not use v16.8.0 or above of react, you can implement the above logic by using a class componnet

```
class Routes extends React.Component {
    state = {isLoading: true, authenticated: false};

    async componentDidMount() {
         const isAuth = await isAuthenticated();
         this.setState({isLoading: false, authenticated: isAuth});
    }

    render() {
        if(state.isLoading) {
           return <Loader/>
        }
        return (
          <BrowserRouter>
            <Fragment>
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={SignIn} />
                <PrivateRoute path="/app" isAuthenticated={state.authenticated} component={App} />
              </Switch>
              <ModalContainer />
            </Fragment>
          </BrowserRouter>
        );
      }

}

export default Routes;
```

Comment: I have done similar thing in the past and it surely does the job.

Comment: What is `isAuthenticated={}`? It gives me an error: `Syntax error: JSX attributes must only be assigned a non-empty expression (42:52)`

Comment: Also it can not found useState, useEffect and Loader: not defined

Comment: Well, Loader is a component, you either you write a component that shows a loading spinner of simply replace it with `<div>Loading....</div>`. Now useEffect and useState need to be imported from react `import React, { useState, useEffect} from 'react'`

Comment: Now I got an eror on `const Routes = () => {`: `TypeError: Object(...) is not a function`

Comment: Could you check the "update 1" in the post? I have paste my code not sure what is wrong,

Comment: @placplacboom are you using v16.8.0 or above in react

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri no: `npm list react
airbnb-web@0.1.0 /Users/placplac/github/blog-adonis-reactjs-react-native-airbnb-web
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@16.4.2 `. I'm using 16.4.2

Comment: Okk, useState and useEffect have been introduced in v16.8.0. However you can make use of class component. I will update my post

Comment: Doesn't need to call `checkAuth`? My page stuck on "Loading..."

Comment: Yes you need to call checkAuth, I updated that part too.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I have a last question: what I need to change to redirect to login page when `const isAuth = await isAuthenticated();` is false? It's alwasy opening my PrivateRoute

Comment: The way you have written your PrivateRoute should work, is it not redirecting?

Comment: No, it's not working. Not sure why it's not working with Promises. If I remove the promise and return a boolean, it works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214064/discussion-between-shubham-khatri-and-placplacboom).

Answer (score 0):

It could be because `isAuthenticated()` returns a Promise which gets seen as a truthy value and therefore the ternary condition will render the component.

Give this a try instead:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={async (props) => {
      const authenticated = await isAuthenticated();
      return authenticated ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/", state: { from: props.location } }} />
      )
    }
    }
  />
);
```

I think this should work unless the `render` prop for the `Route` component doesn't allow for asynchronous functions.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you store your progress and return depending on it:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  const [finished, setFinished] = useState(false);
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    isAuthenticated().then(result => {
      setFinished(true);
      setIsAuthenticated(result);
    });
  }, []);

  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      finished && isAuthenticated ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : finished && !isAuthenticated ? (
        <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/", state: { from: props.location } }} />
      ) : null
    }
  />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to wait for the promise to be resolved you can show a loading message when the result of `isAuthenticated()` is `undefined` :

```js
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    const isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated();


    if (isAuthenticated === undefined) {
        return <p>
           Loading ...
        </p>
    }
    return isAuthenticated ?
    <Route  {...rest} render={props => <Component {...props}/>} /> :
    <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/", state: { from: props.location } }} />
}
```